# Appium - Check if the device has biometrics/Fingerprint

Tags: appium-android, appium-ios

Using Appium how to check if the device has fingerprint or biometrics enabled or has respective hardware?

There are sections in the mobile app which will be displayed only if the device has biometrics enabled, wondering how do i check that.

FYI: with Java/TestNG/Maven.

Comment: Please explain more, do you want to check presence of section?

Comment: There are certain sections of the app which will be displayed only when the device has biometrics enabled, so wondering how to find if biometrics settings is enabled on the device or if that hardware is not available, either of the finding will work.